# How to Dynamically disable dates in DatePicker - Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datepicker

I am using this Plugin: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I have a DropDown which sends an Ajax Request to the Server to load a list/Array of Dates, then I need to only enable the Dates in that Array in the DateTime Picker. I have created a Similar Scenario on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/sd2gmhop/12/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: Countries, optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', value: SelecteItem"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="main-label">Date</label>
        <div class='input-group date'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" data-bind="datepicker: SelectedDate" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

My DateTime Custom Binder:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            defaultDate: valueAccessor()()
        };

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                options.format = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : options.format;
            }
        }

        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });

        var defaultVal = $(element).val();
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(moment(defaultVal, options.format));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // when ViewModel is updated, update the DatePicker Control
        var thisFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                thisFormat = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : thisFormat;
            }
        }

        var value = valueAccessor();
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value());

        if (unwrapped === undefined || unwrapped === null) {
            element.value = new moment(new Date());
            console.log("undefined");
        } else {
            element.value = unwrapped.format(thisFormat);
        }
    }
};
```

And the ViewModel:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Countries = ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']);
    self.SelecteItem = ko.observable();
    self.EnabledDates = ko.observableArray();
    self.SelectedDate = ko.observable(new Date());

    self.SelecteItem.subscribe(function () {
        self.EnabledDates = [];
        if (self.SelecteItem() == "France") {

            self.EnabledDates.push(new moment('Date(1431514972533)'));
            self.EnabledDates.push(new moment('Date(1431082972533)'));

        } else {
            self.EnabledDates.push(new moment(new Date()));
        }


    });
}

var testviewModel = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(testviewModel);
```

How can I only enable Dates in `EnabledDates` Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom binding that observes EnabledDates and applies the changes to the calendar.

**Some Notes of caution** on how you are setting the enabled dates:

**1**  You are actually disposing the observable array by assigning the
    variable a simple array:
    so this:

```
self.EnabledDates = [];
```

should be:

```
self.EnabledDates([]);
```

**2**  The way you are loading the array is not efficient since you are triggering all the watchers (computables and bindings) of that observable everytime you load an element into the array, the best way is to use a temporary array to load all your enabled dates and then load that array into the observable array, this way it only triggers once:

```
       self.SelecteItem.subscribe(function () {
            var tempArray = [];
            if (self.SelecteItem() == "France") {

                tempArray.push(new moment('Date(1431514972533)'));
                tempArray.push(new moment('Date(1431082972533)'));

            } else {
                tempArray.push(new moment(new Date()));
            }
            self.EnabledDates(tempArray);

        });
```

Read more about this here:
http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

**Finally the Custom Binding**:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enableDisable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.enableDisable.update(element,valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var enabledDates =   valueAccessor()();
    //apply disabled dates
    $(element).data("DateTimePicker").enabledDates(enabledDates);
    }
}
```

**Fiddle here**: http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/sd2gmhop/10/